# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tradeTextField

Tags: ios, uitableview

My App has a TableView, with PrototypeCells (CustomCells). There are 4 Sections and each Section has only one row. The first three cells are identical, they all have a UITextField (tradeTextField). But the fourth cell (Class ResultCell) has a custom label in the middle. In InterfaceBuilder i put the number of Prototype Cell to two and i changed the Basic Class to ResultCell and also changed the identifier to resultCell. and now i'm getting the error

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tradeTextField.'
```

Here is the method cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.section == 3) //Here i'm getting the error
{
    ResultCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"resultCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.resultLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
else
{
    TradeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tradeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}   
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Try to inspect your storyboard for unexisting connections to IBOulet. If you delete outlet in your code, connection from IB still exists.

Comment: The App crashes when dataSource asks the ResultCell for Content. The ResultCell contains a UILabel in the middle, and this IBOutlet is properly connected to the Code. i checked it. When i delete this cell, the app runs and the other cells are displayed correctly.

Comment: The error says: i want to create a TextField but the cell doesn't has one. And this is correct. But i specified another cellIdentifier, but the compiler doesn't recognize that

Comment: Have you try clean&build?

Comment: i cleaned, built, and even deleted the app in the simulator and restarted my app again and nothing happend. i'm still getting the error. Maybe there is something wrong with the ViewController in the Storyboard. I made the same thing a month ago and it worked. But now i'm getting this error.

Comment: Omg, it works now. The Problem was the following. The second prototypeCell in the Storyboard was a copy of the first, and the old connections made to the fist cell were also applied for the second Cell and this was wrong, i deleted the worng connection and it works.